# Display different text based on radio button AND checkbox selection

Tags: javascript

I am trying to recreate a small snippet of code (the example can be found [here](https://www.redirecthealth.com/self-employed-health/) when you scroll down to the price selector/"Get Started" selection). I'm trying to have the main price change when  I  click on the "Yes, a member uses tobacco" checkbox, and then when it is unchecked, I want it to go back to the original  price. I'm very close, but I just can't seem  to  find  the last bit of code  that ties it all together. Any help  would be  appreciated!

```js
function setPrice() {
    var radios = document.getElementsByName("radio");
    var selected = Array.from(radios).find(radio => radio.checked);
    document.getElementById('price').innerHTML = selected.value;

    var myself = document.getElementById('m').checked;
    var MS = document.getElementById('ms').checked;
    var MC = document.getElementById('mc').checked;
    var MF = document.getElementById('mf').checked;

    var smoker = document.getElementById('smoker').checked;
    if (smoker === true) {
        document.getElementById('m').value = '394';
        console.log(document.getElementById('m').value);

    } else {
        document.getElementById('m').value = '319';
        console.log(document.getElementById('m').value);

    }
    if (myself === true) {
        document.getElementById('link').href = "https://www.1enrollment.com/order/checkout.cfm?id=575916&pdid=30894&benefitid=51&bSmoker=0&step=2&periodid=1";
    } else if (MS === true) {
        document.getElementById('link').href = "https://www.1enrollment.com/order/checkout.cfm?id=575916&pdid=30894&benefitid=41&bSmoker=0&step=2&periodid=1";
    } else if (MC === true) {
        document.getElementById('link').href = "https://www.1enrollment.com/order/checkout.cfm?id=575916&pdid=30894&benefitid=117&bSmoker=0&step=2&periodid=1";
    } else {
        document.getElementById('link').href = "https://www.1enrollment.com/order/checkout.cfm?id=575916&pdid=30894&benefitid=146&bSmoker=0&step=2&periodid=1";
    }

}
```

```html
  <div class="card">
    <div class="bg-white rounded-18 p-16 relative z-1">
       <ul class="list-reset text-16 font-bold flex-grow-0 flex-shrink-0 flex flex-col justify-between">
          <li>
             <div class="mb-18 text-center flex-grow-0 flex-shrink-0">
                <h4 class="flex justify-center items-center leading-none text-blue-light" style="margin-bottom: 0rem;"><span class="flex-grow-0 flex-shrink-0 text-24 md:text-48 -ml-14 md:-ml-20">$</span> <span class="flex-grow-0 flex-shrink-0 h1_xl2" id="price">319</span></h4>
                <p class="text-18 font-normal" style="margin-bottom: 1rem">PER MONTH</p>
             </div>
          </li>
          <li class="mb-4 flex-grow-0 flex-shrink-0">
             <div class="mb-8">
                <label class="check_box">
                   <input type="radio" id="m" name="radio" onclick="setPrice()" checked="true"> 
                   <div class="flex justify-between flex-wrap text-14 sm:text-16 text-blue-light"><span class="flex-grow-0 flex-shrink-0 text-12 sm:text-16">Myself</span> <span class="flex-grow-0 flex-shrink-0 ml-4" id="myselfSmoke">$319/mo.</span></div>
                   <span class="radiomark"></span>
                </label>
             </div>
          </li>
          <li class="mb-4 flex-grow-0 flex-shrink-0">
             <div class="mb-8">
                <label class="check_box">
                   <input type="radio" id="ms" name="radio" onclick="setPrice()"> 
                   <div class="flex justify-between flex-wrap text-14 sm:text-16"><span class="flex-grow-0 flex-shrink-0 text-12 sm:text-16">Myself + Spouse</span> <span class="flex-grow-0 flex-shrink-0 ml-4" id="msSmoke">$639/mo.</span></div>
                   <span class="radiomark"></span>
                </label>
             </div>
          </li>
          <li class="mb-4 flex-grow-0 flex-shrink-0">
             <div class="mb-8">
                <label class="check_box">
                   <input type="radio" id="mc" name="radio" onclick="setPrice()"> 
                   <div class="flex justify-between flex-wrap text-14 sm:text-16"><span class="flex-grow-0 flex-shrink-0 text-12 sm:text-16">Myself + Children</span> <span class="flex-grow-0 flex-shrink-0 ml-4" id="mcSmoke">$639/mo.</span></div>
                   <span class="radiomark"></span>
                </label>
             </div>
          </li>
          <li class="mb-4 flex-grow-0 flex-shrink-0">
             <div class="mb-8">
                <label class="check_box">
                   <input type="radio" id="mf" name="radio" onclick="setPrice()"> 
                   <div class="flex justify-between flex-wrap text-14 sm:text-16"><span class="flex-grow-0 flex-shrink-0 text-12 sm:text-16">Myself + Family</span> <span class="flex-grow-0 flex-shrink-0 ml-4" id="mfSmoke">$899/mo.</span></div>
                   <span class="radiomark"></span>
                </label>
             </div>
          </li>
          <li class="flex-grow-0 flex-shrink-0 p-8 -mx-8 rounded-6 bg-blue-light">
             <label class="check_box">
                <input type="checkbox" name="areYouASmoker" id="smoker" onclick="setPrice()"> 
                <div class="text-white">
                   <p class="text-14 leading-none text-center mr-32 md:mr-0">Yes. A member uses tobacco.</p>
                   <p class="text-12 leading-none font-normal text-center mr-32">($75 surcharge)</p>
                </div>
                <span class="checkmark"></span>
             </label>
          </li>
       </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I use another way to achieve the same objective. I believe there must be another better way to do this, but I am using `for loop` to loop through the price and change its `innerHtml` and also the `value` of the radio button. The HTML code is different from what you provide, but the logic is same. Correct me if I am wrong!

Every time the radio button is clicked, it will fire the `updatePrice` function and pass in the element which call the it. The function will then update the price.

When the checkbox is clicked, it will call `inc_dec_price` function, which will check whether the checkbox is checked or not, then increase or decrease the price.

```js
function inc_dec_price(){
    var prices = document.getElementsByClassName('prices');
    var radios = document.getElementsByName('opt');
        
    if(document.getElementById('smoker').checked){
    for(var i = 0; i < prices.length; i++){
        prices[i].innerHTML = parseInt(prices[i].innerHTML) + 75
            radios[i].value = prices[i].innerHTML;
        }
    }
    else {
        for(var i = 0; i < prices.length; i++){
            prices[i].innerHTML -= 75
            radios[i].value = prices[i].innerHTML
        }
    }
    updatePrice(Array.from(radios).find(e => e.checked))
}

function updatePrice(element){
    document.getElementById('to_pay').innerHTML = element.value
}
```

```html
<h1>$ <span id="to_pay">319</span></h1>
    <ul>
        <li><input type="radio" onclick="updatePrice(this);" value="319" id="opt-0" name="opt" checked><label for="opt-0">Myself  $ <span class="prices">319</span>/month</label></li>
        <li><input type="radio" onclick="updatePrice(this);" value="639" id="opt-1" name="opt"><label for="opt-1">Myself + Spouse $ <span class="prices">639</span>/month</label></li>
        <li><input type="radio" onclick="updatePrice(this);" value="639" id="opt-2" name="opt"><label for="opt-2">Myself + Children$ <span class="prices">639</span>/month</label></li>
        <li><input type="radio" onclick="updatePrice(this);" value="899" id="opt-3" name="opt"><label for="opt-3">Myself + Family $ <span class="prices">899</span>/month</label></li>
    </ul>
    <input type="checkbox" name="smoker" id="smoker" onclick="inc_dec_price()"><label for="smoker">Yes, A member uses tobacco ($75 surcharge) </label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution you can check this. I change **if** Condition

```
if (smoker === true) {
         
       document.getElementById('price').innerHTML = '394';
        console.log(document.getElementById('price').innerHTML);

    } else {
        document.getElementById('m').value = '319';
        console.log(document.getElementById('m').value);

    }
```

```js
function setPrice() {
    var radios = document.getElementsByName("radio");
    var selected = Array.from(radios).find(radio => radio.checked);
    document.getElementById('price').innerHTML = selected.value;

    var myself = document.getElementById('m').checked;
    var MS = document.getElementById('ms').checked;
    var MC = document.getElementById('mc').checked;
    var MF = document.getElementById('mf').checked;

    var smoker = document.getElementById('smoker').checked;
    console.log("smoker",smoker);
    if (smoker === true) {
         
       document.getElementById('price').innerHTML = '394';
        console.log(document.getElementById('price').innerHTML);

    } else {
        document.getElementById('m').value = '319';
        console.log(document.getElementById('m').value);

    }
    if (myself === true && smoker === false) {
    document.getElementById('price').innerHTML = '319';
        document.getElementById('link').href = "https://www.1enrollment.com/order/checkout.cfm?id=575916&pdid=30894&benefitid=51&bSmoker=0&step=2&periodid=1";
    } else if (MS === true && smoker === false) {
    document.getElementById('price').innerHTML = '639';
        document.getElementById('link').href = "https://www.1enrollment.com/order/checkout.cfm?id=575916&pdid=30894&benefitid=41&bSmoker=0&step=2&periodid=1";
    } else if (MC === true && smoker === false) {
    document.getElementById('price').innerHTML = '639';
        document.getElementById('link').href = "https://www.1enrollment.com/order/checkout.cfm?id=575916&pdid=30894&benefitid=117&bSmoker=0&step=2&periodid=1";
    } else if(MF===true && smoker === false) {
    document.getElementById('price').innerHTML = '899';
        document.getElementById('link').href = "https://www.1enrollment.com/order/checkout.cfm?id=575916&pdid=30894&benefitid=146&bSmoker=0&step=2&periodid=1";
    }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card">
    <div class="bg-white rounded-18 p-16 relative z-1">
       <ul class="list-reset text-16 font-bold flex-grow-0 flex-shrink-0 flex flex-col justify-between">
          <li>
             <div class="mb-18 text-center flex-grow-0 flex-shrink-0">
                <h4 id="h4" class="flex justify-center items-center leading-none text-blue-light" style="margin-bottom: 0rem;"><span class="flex-grow-0 flex-shrink-0 text-24 md:text-48 -ml-14 md:-ml-20">$</span> <span class="flex-grow-0 flex-shrink-0 h1_xl2" id="price">319</span></h4>
                <p class="text-18 font-normal" style="margin-bottom: 1rem">PER MONTH</p>
             </div>
          </li>
          <li class="mb-4 flex-grow-0 flex-shrink-0">
             <div class="mb-8">
              <a id="link"></a>
                <label class="check_box">
               
                   <input type="radio" id="m" name="radio" onclick="setPrice()" checked="true"> 
                   <div class="flex justify-between flex-wrap text-14 sm:text-16 text-blue-light"><span class="flex-grow-0 flex-shrink-0 text-12 sm:text-16">Myself</span> <span class="flex-grow-0 flex-shrink-0 ml-4" id="myselfSmoke">$319/mo.</span></div>
                   <span class="radiomark"></span>
                </label>
             </div>
          </li>
          <li class="mb-4 flex-grow-0 flex-shrink-0">
             <div class="mb-8">
                <label class="check_box">
                   <input type="radio" id="ms" name="radio" onclick="setPrice()"> 
                   <div class="flex justify-between flex-wrap text-14 sm:text-16"><span class="flex-grow-0 flex-shrink-0 text-12 sm:text-16">Myself + Spouse</span> <span class="flex-grow-0 flex-shrink-0 ml-4" id="msSmoke">$639/mo.</span></div>
                   <span class="radiomark"></span>
                </label>
             </div>
          </li>
          <li class="mb-4 flex-grow-0 flex-shrink-0">
             <div class="mb-8">
                <label class="check_box">
                   <input type="radio" id="mc" name="radio" onclick="setPrice()"> 
                   <div class="flex justify-between flex-wrap text-14 sm:text-16"><span class="flex-grow-0 flex-shrink-0 text-12 sm:text-16">Myself + Children</span> <span class="flex-grow-0 flex-shrink-0 ml-4" id="mcSmoke">$639/mo.</span></div>
                   <span class="radiomark"></span>
                </label>
             </div>
          </li>
          <li class="mb-4 flex-grow-0 flex-shrink-0">
             <div class="mb-8">
                <label class="check_box">
                   <input type="radio" id="mf" name="radio" onclick="setPrice()"> 
                   <div class="flex justify-between flex-wrap text-14 sm:text-16"><span class="flex-grow-0 flex-shrink-0 text-12 sm:text-16">Myself + Family</span> <span class="flex-grow-0 flex-shrink-0 ml-4" id="mfSmoke">$899/mo.</span></div>
                   <span class="radiomark"></span>
                </label>
             </div>
          </li>
          <li class="flex-grow-0 flex-shrink-0 p-8 -mx-8 rounded-6 bg-blue-light">
             <label class="check_box">
                <input type="checkbox" name="areYouASmoker" id="smoker" onclick="setPrice()"> 
                <div class="text-white">
                   <p class="text-14 leading-none text-center mr-32 md:mr-0">Yes. A member uses tobacco.</p>
                   <p class="text-12 leading-none font-normal text-center mr-32">($75 surcharge)</p>
                </div>
                <span class="checkmark"></span>
             </label>
          </li>
       </ul>
    </div>
```